# Nexus 5 Camera.Face object is null?

Tags: java, android, camera, face-detection

Here is my [code on gist](https://gist.github.com/gonjay/9359598)

This camera app is follow [Android Official Guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#custom-camera)

My device is Nexus 5 with kikat 4.4.2

```
    @Override
    public void onFaceDetection(Camera.Face[] faces, Camera camera) {
      if (faces.length > 0){
        Camera.Face f = faces[0];
        Log.v(TAG, ("Detected" + faces.length + "faces，the ID of first face is：" + f.id ));

        Log.v(TAG, "leftEye : " + f.leftEye);
        Log.v(TAG, "mouth   : " + f.mouth);
        Log.v(TAG, "rect    : " + f.rect);
        Log.v(TAG, "rightEye: " + f.rightEye);

        mCamera.stopFaceDetection();
    }
}
```

The output above code when detect a human face is:

```
Detected 1 faces，the ID of first face is：-1
FaceActivity﹕ leftEye : null
FaceActivity﹕ mouth   : null
FaceActivity﹕ rect    : Rect(-393, 356 - -213, 676)
FaceActivity﹕ rightEye: null
```

So, I want to know whether my Nexus 5 support FaceDetect?If not, how could it implement Screen  Lock with Face Unlock?

Comment: `Nexus 5 with kikat 4.3.2` ????? did you mean Nexus 5 with `kikat 4.4.2` ?

Comment: I'm sorry to type it wrong...But why my question was voted down?

Comment: I didnt downvote your question. Somebody else did it.

Comment: I have solve this problem, but thank you anyway...I got a Google Glass recently,and I want to develop a Face Recognize App on it.Do you have some suggestions?

Comment: Suggestion : Google is nice place :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the reason for this problem. It's all about `RGB_564`. Android has an API to recognize the human face, but only `RGB_564` bitmaps are supported. Face detection is a very cost intensive action. So by default, the camera's FaceDetect feature only recognizes basic face information, and that was the reason why `face.leftEye` is null.